# Recursive constructor invocation?

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

```java
public class RGBImage {

    private RGBColor[][] _image;

    public RGBImage(RGBColor[][] pixels) {
        _image = new RGBColor[pixels.length][pixels[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _image.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _image[i].length; j++)
                _image[i][j] = new RGBColor(pixels[i][j]);
    }

    public RGBImage(RGBImage other) {
        this(new RGBImage(other._image));
    }
```

The second constructor is supposed to call the first one, but instead gives me the "Recursive constructor invocation" error.
I understand what the error means, I just don't understand where the recursion is. The first contructor takes `RGBColor[][]` as a parameter, and `other._image` is supposed to be an array of that type. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `this(other._image);` instead.

Comment: It *does* call the first one, but *also* creates a new `RGBImage`, because you use `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second constructor should probably look like this:

```java
public RGBImage(RGBImage other) {
    this(other._image);
}
```

Your version creates yet another instance which creates yet another instance and so on. `this()` is already calling the other constructor, no need to `new` a new instance.